# Bitcoin Research

Tags: cryptography, academic-research

I have recently been assigned to advise a student on a senior thesis in math.  She has taken linear algebra, introductory real analysis, basic cryptography, and abstract algebra.  Her interest is in cryptography.  And she has a love of Bitcoin.  The point of a senior thesis is to get a student to teach themselves a subject and learn to find and read mathematical papers.  Original work that could be published would be nice, but is often untenable.

My question is whether anyone knows of any research that is/has being/been done in cryptography related to Bitcoin.  Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: [Are there scientific studies related to the Bitcoin technology?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/bitcoin-research). Maybe even a duplicate, though I'm not sure the other one is up to date. Perhaps people can add more recent information to that one.

Comment: Cross posted here for those who are interested: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/bitcoin-research

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the Research article on the Bitcoin wiki:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Research

You might find some of the authors in the list have related research that is not directly related to Bitcoin so is absent from that list.